# How to resize an input with img HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to resize input text When using mobile version but I don't know how, Can you help me
Ex: How do you auto-resize a large [ input text ] so that it will fit into a smaller width div container whilst maintaining its width:height ratio?
This is my script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ex.</title>
<style>
img {
    width: 100%; /* or any custom size */
    height: 100%; 
    object-fit: contain;
}

</style>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="dr.s1x" onSubmit="return false">
<!-- dr.s1x --> 
 <div id="ph1">
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jKF3Dz/Screenshot_2018_07_29_10_50_49.png" ondragstart="return false;"/>
    <input class="gredient_input" type="email" placeholder="Email" id="usr0" name="usr0" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; visibility: visible; left: 66px; top: 143px; width: 660px; height: 44px;" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" onKeyDown="doSomething1()" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)" />
    <input class="gredient_input" type="password" placeholder="Mot de passe" id="usr1" name="usr1" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; visibility: visible; left: 66px; top: 192px; width: 656px; height: 44px;" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1" onKeyDown="doSomething2()" />
        <a class="close" style="position: absolute; left: 62px; top: 257px; width: 679px; height: 44px; visibility: visible;" onClick="master()"></a>

  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. You have to define the rules of sizing that input so that nobody can understand differently than what you mean. Right now it's likely 4 out of 5 people understand different things from your requirement. What exactly do you want to determine the input's width? The parent's width, the device width, the width in px of the `<img>`? What exactly do you want to determine the the input's height? A particular ratio of the width? A ratio of device or parent width? Or of their height? Please describe it so there is no confusion whatsoever.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "it will fit"? Will it stretch, will it downsize keeping a particular ratio between width and height? What sets that ratio? Is it different on devices with different width/height ratio? Is it different in landscape/portrait modes?

Comment: When I want to open a page in the mobile
The image size changes only
I want to change <input... with her
look   https://i.imgur.com/jTWCCIH.png

Comment: When I want to change the page size
I want to change the input size with it [width,height]

Comment: please see the script
I want to change input position with img

Comment: In theory, what you want to achieve is doable but, from my POV, there are way too many things wrong with your approach to be worth pointing them out or fixing them and explaining why they're wrong. I suggest you read more on best practices in CSS and perhaps use a popular framework to achieve your desired layout. I can't even begin to describe how wrong the idea of a background with painted inputs is, for starters. You really need to do some reading.

Comment: I do not want to read only I want to correct me
If you have experience in this field
Just copy in your html programme
and correction If you have experience
I want to put input text in the picture and
When I change the page size I want to change the size of the input

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
img {
    width: 100%; /* or any custom size */
    height: 100%; 
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

and

```
input {
    width: 100%; /* or any custom size */
    height: 100%; 
    object-fit: contain;
}
```